# Error after OLE DB driver up-gradation (Specified driver could not be loaded due to system error 5 )

Tags: sql-server, oledb, openedge

We get the following error message, after installing a latest version of a OLE DB driver for SQL server 2008. Any thoughts ?

```
 OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "*****" returned message 
    "Specified driver could not be loaded due to system error  5 
(Progress OpenEdge 11.0 Driver).".
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Error 5 usually stands for "access denied", although I don't see the relevance in this context.

Comment: Does this help? http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/4827?q=%22system+error+5%22&l=en_US&fs=Search&pn=1

Comment: @Jensd : Your link was correct. It worked thanks. Permission was the issue.